# How to get the value of option selected from JOptionPane.showMessageDialog?

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane, japplet, game-development

I am making a java game. This is a piece of my code in which I have a question.

How to get the value (no matter index value or string value) of option selected?
I have to use it later in my code, for instance `if(n="5 point game") { do this}`

```
newgame=new JButton("NEW GAME");
newgame.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
      Object[] options = {"5 point game",
            "Non stop game"};
      int n = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(newgame,
                                           "Choose a mode to play ",
                                           "New Game",
                                            JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
                                            JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
                                            null,     //do not use a custom Icon
                                            options,  //the titles of buttons
                                            options[0]); //default button title
}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your options must be sorted as the buttons will be without your custom options. In your case, this means that `options[0]` is mapped to `JOptionPane.YES_OPTION` and `options[1]` to `JOptionPane.NO_OPTION`.

For your code, you can use an if-statement like this:

```
if (n == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
    // 5 point game
}
else if (n == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {
    // non stop game
}
else {
    // the user closed the dialog without clicking an button
}
```

See also [this example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/DialogDemoProject/src/components/DialogDemo.java).